# github page no carga las imagenes ni las paginas href

Tags: html5, css3, github-pages

https://berllliin.github.io/Mudanzas/ visualización de pagina

https://github.com/Berllliin/Mudanzas.git codigo

tambien intente cambiar los src y los href pero no encuentro la solucion

no se si las rutas estan mal o van diferente el proyecto lo visualizo bien en visual studio code por live server pero en github no puedo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

holaa,fijate que tenes mal la ruta ya que en la primera imagen es la forma correcta y en el resto pones un / de mas, si no entendiste mírate la consola :D

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).